# Javascript/PHP Unexpected Token ';' on JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I've got a page that's making an AJAX POST request to PHP, PHP is querying MySQL, and returning a JSON object that countains the query response. This all had been working, but it stopped and I can't figure out what went wrong.

Here's the JS that makes the request, getDriver.js

```
var driverList = [];

$.ajax({
    url: './php/GetDriverList.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var tempList = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++){
            driverList.push(tempList[i]);
        }
        buildTable(driverList);
    }
});
```

And here's the PHP, GetDriverList.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "USE test") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM drivers WHERE 
    isActive = 1");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$return = json_encode($rows);
echo $return;
?>;
```

The error message is the following:

```
Error:
VM6389:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 183
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (getDrivers.js:9)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
success @ getDrivers.js:9
u @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ getDrivers.js:5
```

I removed some comments in getDrivers.js, line 9 corresponds to "console.log(response)". However, this line fails to log to the console.

Finally, the JSON object that I pulled out of the network tab of the console in Chrome is the following:

```
[{"id":"2","fname":"XXXX","lname":"XXXX"},
{"id":"3","fname":"XXXX","lname":"XXXX"},
{"id":"4","fname":"XXXX","lname":"XXXX"},
{"id":"5","fname":"XXXX","lname":"XXXX"}];
```

Please help! What's wrong with my JSON object all of a sudden?

Comment: ; is not expected there. check why you are getting that. that cause of error

Comment: Json data can't contain `;` at the end. You are something missing in encoding data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `?>;`, remove the `;` there because also belongs to the output that is send to the client.

When I used php it was a good practice to omit the last `?>` in general and only add it if there is really data that has to be displayed. That reduces the probability that accidentally add unwanted output.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies for typographical mistake

Comment: *sent to the client

Comment: @FelixKling thank you. corrected the sentence.

Comment: This was it, thank you! Since the code worked before and I couldn't remember making any major edits, I knew it had to be some small dumb thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken you have not added dataType in your ajax call.

**dataType** informs which type of data to be expected from response, which in your case json.

```
var driverList = [];

$.ajax({
    url: './php/GetDriverList.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var tempList = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++){
            driverList.push(tempList[i]);
        }
        buildTable(driverList);
    }
});
```